# Elm open url in a new tab

Tags: elm

I am trying to learn Elm and trying to figure how to open a url in a new tab instead of the same page.

The following piece of code opens the URL in same page:

```
Browser.Navigation.load (url)
```

what do I need to replace this with so this URL opens in a new tab?

Comment: If you want to open the page on a user action like a click, you could simply use the standard link tag with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to easily do this with ports.

```
port module Main exposing (main)

port newTab : String -> Cmd msg
```

and in JS

```
app.ports.newTab.subscribe( url => window.open(url, '_blank'));
```

[2021-02-22] edit:

The above solution assumes that the programmer wants to open an url programmatically (from the `update` function) and that `Html.target_ "_blank"` was not an option.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work in my Main.elm file. Is there an import or something needed for window? It complains that it cannot find the window variable

Comment: The `window.open` part rests in the javascript file as the implementation of the port. It is not part of the Elm file. See the `JavaScript Interop` section of the official Guide for more information.

Comment: While this would work, I recommend using @Niavlys' solution if possible because it's more idiomatic for a web page in general.

Comment: If `Html.target_ "_blank"` can be used, it should be used. My solution assumed that the person wanted to open a link from the `update` function.

Answer (score 3):

An Elm app doesn’t manage your browser tabs, just the one tab in which it is currently running (neither does a JS app, by the way!).

So the `Browser.Navigation` API is of no use here, you must simply use a plain HTML `a` with `target="_blank"`, as @viam0zah commented:

```
Html.a [ Html.Attributes.target "_blank"] [ Html.text "Open in a new tab" ]
```